# Error: Could not find or load main class: Scala IDE/Spark

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am building a spark application using scala-ide. While running my class from the eclipse there are no class files getting generated and its throwing me-

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

When I am building my project through maven my class file are getting generated and the program is getting executed in eclipse too. But too run the job while doing development I cant keep on building using maven again and again. My pom.xml looks like-

```
 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.11</scala.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.4.4</version> </dependency> -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory> <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <!-- Additional configuration. -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have checked that my versions are correct(maven build would have failed if it would have been otherwise), and also my directory structure seems to be correct-

[image: Directory structure of project]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are you running the class? and can you update the framework of the class if possible whole code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some error in your build path: `Right click in project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path`